# Python Merge, merges all column, fails with specific column

Tags: python, pandas

i have 2 dataframes that i want to merge and only bring 1 column over, (the other column is the matching 'on' column).  This works... but brings in both columns

```py
vlookup = df1.merge(df2, left_on='team', right_on='mrTeams', how='left')
```

[image]

**BUT** if i add the specific column name, it fails with Key Error: 'mrTeams'

```py
vlookup = df1.merge(df2[['fullname']], left_on='team', right_on='mrTeams', how='left')
```

Comment: `df2[['fullname']]` has only one column, namely `'fullname'`. So you may want to do: `df2[['mrTeams','fullname']]`.

Comment: adding these 2 column names brings both columns in... it defeats what i am trying to do. I dont want 2 exact same columns, which are the columns i match the data on which are identical. like the 3rd tbale in screenshot.  I want the other column.

Comment: Do as @henrywongkk suggested in his answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df2[['fullname']]` will give you a dataframe with one column `'fullname' only

if you don't want `'mrTeams'` column to be appeared in the `vlookup` dataframe, you can rename the column to `'team'` before `merge`

```py
vlookup = df1.merge(df2.rename(columns{"mrTeams": "team"}), left_on='team', right_on='team', how='left')
```